# What does a private coin $\mathsf{IP}$ protocol for Hilbert's Nullstellensatz look like?

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, algebra, polynomials, algebraic-complexity

**$\mathsf{GNI}$ Private Coin**

In [[GMW85]](https://people.csail.mit.edu/silvio/Selected%20Scientific%20Papers/Zero%20Knowledge/Proofs_That_Yield_Nothing_But_Their_Validity_or_All_Languages_in_NP_Have_Zero-Knowledge_Proof_Systems.pdf), the authors provided the famous interactive proof $\mathsf{IP}$ of Graph Non Isomorphism $\mathsf{GNI}$.

The $\mathsf{GNI}$ protocol entails a verifier Vicky picking a random permutation $\pi$ to permute the edges of one of the two given graphs $G_i$, with $i\in\{0,1\}$, to generate a new graph $\pi(G_i)$, and providing the prover Peggy with, say, an adjacency matrix of $\pi(G_i)$.

Peggy must answer whether $i=0$ or $i=1$.  The success of the protocol depended on Vicky keeping $(i, \pi)$ secret from Peggy.

---

**$\mathsf{GNI}$ Public Coin**

As is known, in [[GS86]](http://crypto.cs.mcgill.ca/~crepeau/COMP647/2007/TOPIC01/goldwasser-Sipser.pdf), the authors showed that, with more work on the prover's part, Merlin can show to Arthur that two graphs are not isomorphic, where Arthur *publicly shows* all of his coinflips to Arthur.

As I understand it, it came as a bit of a surprise that the *private coin* protocol $\mathsf{IP}$ is just as powerful as a two-round *public coin* protocol $\mathsf{AM[2]}$.

I envision the [GS86] protocol as Arthur providing to Merlin some $y$, $H$, and Merlin running through both graphs $G_i$, and through all of the permutations $\pi$ of both graphs, until he finds a permutation of one of the graphs such that the hash of the adjacency matrix is $y$, because there are likely to be *more* permutations of non isomorphic graphs, and hence there is likely to be a greater chance of finding a preimage.

That is, Merlin looks for a $\pi$ and an $i$ such that $y=H(\pi(G_i))$.

---

**$\mathsf{HN}$ Public Coin**

In [[Koi96]](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/d4e6/87c5dc96a0e4fd47465792f7b6f694a85e7a.pdf), Koiran provided, assuming the Generalized Riemann Hypothesis, a *public coin* protocol for Hilbert's Nullstellensatz $\mathsf{HN}$, that shows a system of polynomial equations $S$ is solvable over $\mathbb{C}$.  That is, Merlin can show to Arthur that a solution to:

$$f_1[x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]=f_2[x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_n]=\cdots=f_m[x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n]=0$$
exists over $\mathbb{C}^n$.

In the [Koi96] approach, assuming the GRH, there are "many" primes $p$ such that there is a solution to $S$ mod $p$ iff there is a solution to $S$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$.  Of course, "many" can be very small, but it is still much larger than the number of primes if $S$ is *not* solvable in $\mathbb{C}^n$.

The [Koi96] protocol entails Merlin finding a prime $p$ and a solution witness $w=(a_1, a_2, \cdots, a_n)$ such that $S$ is solvable modulo $p$, and further that $H(p)=y$ for some randomly chosen hash $H$ and image $y$.

By appropriately choosing the size of the codomain of $H$ to be small enough to guarantee a high likelihood of a collision when there are many primes $p$, Merlin can find both a prime $p$ and the witness $w$ such that *both* $w$ is a solution mod $p$ *and* $H(p)=y$.

---

**Towards an $\mathsf{HN}$ Private Coin**

There seems to be a difference between the public coin $\mathsf{GNI}$ protocol and the public coin $\mathsf{HN}$ protocol.

In the $\mathsf{AM}$ protocol for $\mathsf{GNI}$, Merlin can do all of the work that Vicky would have done in the $\mathsf{IP}$ protocol.  That is, Merlin just walks through all of the permutations that a private-coin verifier Vicky could have randomly chosen.

For example, in $\mathsf{GNI}$, Vicky can randomly and Merlin can exhaustively easily permute one of the two graphs $G_1$ or $G_2$.

But in [Koi96], it's not clear what a private coin verifier would have been doing in the first place.

Is there a similarly obvious way for Merlin to generate a solution to the system of polynomial equations $S$ modulo some prime $p$, and then leverage that solution to generate many other solutions $S$ modulo other primes $p'$ until he finds a winning solution where $y=H(p')$?

---

**EDIT**

I believe, by analogy to Group Non Membership $\mathsf{GNM}$,a private-coin Hilbert's Nullstellensatz $\mathsf{HN}$ protocol might be a version of Ideal Non Membership $\mathsf{INM}$.

For example, given a finite (matrix) group $G$ of order $|G|$ generated by generators $\langle g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_m\rangle$, Vicky the verifier may ask Peggy the prover to show that the test element $q$ is not in $G$ by flipping a coin $i\in\{1,2\}$ and generating a random word $g^*$ of length $O(\text{log}|G|)$ from either

$$G=G_1=\langle g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_m\rangle$$

or

$$G_2=\langle g_1,g_2,\cdots,g_m,q\rangle$$

If $q\in G$, then the groups $G_i$ are isomorphic, and $G_1\cup G_2$ is of size $|G|$.  However, if $q\notin G$, then $G_1$ and $G_2$ are not isomorphic, and $G_1\cup G_2$  will be at least twice as big.  I think the public coin/ approximate counting protocol for $\mathsf{GNM}$ follows similarly to [GS86] follows.

For a public-coin version of $\mathsf{HN}$, a way to reprhase the (weak) Nullstellensatz is to state that the polynomial $1$ is *not* in the ideal generated by $\langle f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_m \rangle$.  Here Vicky the verifier randomly generates a polynomial $f^*$ of degree $O(\text{poly }mn)$ from *either* $$\langle f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_m\rangle$$

*or* $$\langle f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_m,1\rangle=\langle 1\rangle$$

Peggy the prover's job is to identify whether $f^*$ was generated from $\langle f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_m\rangle$ *or* $\langle f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_m,1\rangle$.

Of course, *all* polynomials are generated by $\langle 1 \rangle$, just as all statements follow from a contradiction.  But perhaps, assuming GRH, the "size" of $\langle f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_m\rangle\cup\langle f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_m,1\rangle$ is bigger than the "size" of$\langle f_1,f_2,\cdots,f_m,1\rangle$ by itself, after "randomly" generating the polynomial $f^*$ with only $\text{poly }mn$ coin flips.  In other words, GRH may place bounds on how fast the ideal $\langle 1\rangle$ generates members.  This may enable Peggy/Merlin the win...